# Segmentation fault in c (C90), Whats the problem?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

Heres my main.c:

```
int main() {
    char *x = "add r3,r5";


    char *t;
    char **end;

    t = getFirstTok(x,end);
    printf("%s",t);
}
```

And the function getFirstTok:

```
/* getFirstTok function returns a pointer to the start of the first token. */
/* Also makes *endOfTok (if it's not NULL) to point at the last char after the token. */
char *getFirstTok(char *str, char **endOfTok)
{
    char *tokStart = str;
    char *tokEnd = NULL;

    /* Trim the start */
    trimLeftStr(&tokStart);

    /* Find the end of the first word */
    tokEnd = tokStart;
    while (*tokEnd != '\0' && !isspace(*tokEnd))
    {
        tokEnd++;
    }

    /* Add \0 at the end if needed */
    if (*tokEnd != '\0')
    {
        *tokEnd = '\0';
        tokEnd++;
    }

    /* Make *endOfTok (if it's not NULL) to point at the last char after the token */
    if (endOfTok)
    {
        *endOfTok = tokEnd;
    }
    return tokStart;
}
```

Why do i get segmentation fault running this main program?
I'm programming a two pass aseembler and i need a function that get parse a string by a delimiter, In this case a white space. Is it better to use strtok instead for this purpose?

I need a command pasrer - So that it will extract "add", an operand parser (By , delimiter), To extract "r3" and "r5". I wanted to check if this getFirstTok function is good for this purpose but when i try to run it i get a segmentation fault:

**Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)**

Thank you.

Comment: You can't modify a string literal, that's undefined behavior.  They're usually in read-only memory and you segfault if you try to write there.  Try with `char x[] = "...";` instead.

Comment: It also looks like you never initialize `end` before using it in the condition.

Comment: `char **end; t = getFirstTok(x, end);` you pass a random (uninitialized, maybe trap-representation) value to the function. I think maybe (?) you want `char *end; t = getFirstTok(x, &end);`

Comment: @anastaciu: Good point.  By analogy with `strtok` you would normally call such a function as `char *endp; t = getFirstTok(x, &endp);`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll revisit this subject again to understand how to use string pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, string literals are read-only, as they are baked into the compiled program. If you don't want to go with the suggested solution of making your "source program" a stack-allocated array of characters (`char x[] = "add r3,r5"`), you can use a function like `strdup(3)` to make a readable/writable copy like so:

```c
#include <string.h>

[...]

char *rw_code = strdup(x);
t = getFirstTok(rw_code, end);
printf("%s", t);
free(rw_code); /* NOTE: invalidates _all_ references pointing at it! */

[...]
```

And as a little aside, I always make string literals constant `const char *lit = "..."`, as the compiler will usually warn me if I attempt to write to them later on.